# which particular field of the model is referred under the foreign key in django's orm?

Tags: django-models

i have two classes 'topics' and 'webpage' and i'm trying to assign webpage.category as a foreign key referencing to topics.top_name.

But unlike raw sql where a foreign key can reference to a particular field in another table, in django's orm we just provide the referenced class'(table's) name and not the particular field the FK is referrring to.

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    top_name = models.CharField(max_length=264, unique=True)
        top_author = models.CharField(max_length=264)

class Webpage(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    url = models.URLField()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the [**`to_field=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field) in the `ForeignKey` constructor:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    top_name = models.CharField(max_length=264, unique=True)
    top_author = models.CharField(max_length=264)

class Webpage(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Topic, to_field='top_name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    url = models.URLField()
```

As specified in the documentation, the field to which you refer should be *unique* (which of course makes sense, since otherwise, it would be ambiguous).

Note that usually, the [collation [mysql-doc]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-column.html) of the referencing column and the target column should be the same. Otherwise it is not completely clear when the two fields are equal.

If you do not specify the `to_field`, it will use the primary key of the target model.